# Find maximum value of a variable given constraints in z3py

Tags: python, z3, z3py

For example, given the following 4 constraints, `a` and `x` are `ints`, `b` is `array`, maps `int` to `int`:

```
a >= 0
b[0] == 10
x == 0
b[x] >= a

find_max(a) => 10
find_min(a) => 0
```

Can z3py do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, sure.

You can either do it incrementally, via multiple single-objective optimization searches, or use the more efficient **boxed** (*a.k.a. Multi-Independent*) combination offered by **z3** for dealing with multi-objective optimization.

> **Definition 4.6.3. (Multiple-Independent OMT [LAK+14, BP14, BPF15, ST15b, ST15c]).**
>   Let `<φ,O>` be a multi-objective OMT problem, where `φ`
>   is a ground SMT formula and `O = {obj_1 , ..., obj_N}`,
>   is a sorted list of `N` objective functions.
>   We call **Multiple-Independent OMT problem**,
>   *a.k.a Boxed OMT problem [BP14, BPF15]*,
>   the problem of finding in one single run a set of
>   models `{M_1, ...,M_N}` such that each `M_i` makes
>   `obj_i` minimum on the common formula `φ`.
>
> > **Remark 4.6.3.** Solving a Multiple-Independent
> >     OMT problem `<φ, {obj_1, ..., obj_N }>` is akin to
> >     independently solving `N` single-objective OMT
> >     problems `<φ, obj_1>, ..., <φ, obj_N>`.
> >     However, the former allows for factorizing the search
> >     and thus obtaining a significant performance boost
> >     when compared to the latter approach [LAK+14, BP14, ST15c].
>
> [[source, pag. 104](http://www.patricktrentin.com/data/phd_thesis/main.pdf)]

**Example:**

```py
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
x = Int('x')
b = Array('I', IntSort(), IntSort())

opt = Optimize()

opt.add(a >= 0)
opt.add(x == 0)
opt.add(Select(b, 0) == 10)
opt.add(Select(b, x) >= a)

obj1 = opt.maximize(a)
obj2 = opt.minimize(a)

opt.set('priority', 'box')   # Setting Boxed Multi-Objective Optimization

is_sat = opt.check()
assert is_sat

print("Max(a): " + str(obj1.value()))
print("Min(a): " + str(obj2.value()))
```

Output:

```
~$ python test.py 
Max(a): 10
Min(a): 0
```

---

See publications on the topic like, e.g.

**1.** *Nikolaj Bjorner and Anh-Dung Phan.* **νZ - Maximal Satisfaction with Z3.** In Proc International Symposium on Symbolic Computation in Software Science, Gammart, Tunisia, December 2014. EasyChair Proceedings in Computing (EPiC). [[PDF]](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nbjorner-scss2014.pdf)

**2.** *Nikolaj Bjorner, Anh-Dung Phan, and Lars Fleckenstein.* **Z3 - An Optimizing SMT Solver.** In Proc. TACAS, volume 9035 of LNCS. Springer, 2015. [[Springer]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-46681-0_14) [[[PDF]](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nbjorner-nuz.pdf)

Comment: Thank you so much @Patrick Trentin, this is EXACTLY what I need. Your answer is perfect!

Comment: Hi, do you think you can answer this question? I think it should be quite simple, but I was unable to find it on google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61198472/how-to-get-existing-constraints-out-of-a-z3-solver-object-in-z3py