# How to get existing constraints out of a Z3 Solver object in z3py?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

For example, I want to get the existing constraints from s and into the Optimize object.

```
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
x = Int('x')
b = Array('I', IntSort(), IntSort())
s = Solver()

s.add(a >= 0)
s.add(x == 0)
s.add(Select(b, 0) == 10)
s.add(Select(b, x) >= a)

opt = Optimize()
opt.add(s.constraints)

obj1 = opt.maximize(a)
obj2 = opt.minimize(a)

opt.set('priority', 'box')   # Setting Boxed Multi-Objective Optimization

is_sat = opt.check()
assert is_sat

print("Max(a): " + str(obj1.value()))
print("Min(a): " + str(obj2.value()))
```

Then the result would be like this.

```
~$ python test.py 
Max(a): 10
Min(a): 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one wants to get a vector of all constraints added to a `Solver` (or `Optimize`) instance, one can use the method `assertions()`:

> ```
>  |  assertions(self)
>  |      Return an AST vector containing all added constraints.
>  |      
>  |      >>> s = Solver()
>  |      >>> s.assertions()
>  |      []
>  |      >>> a = Int('a')
>  |      >>> s.add(a > 0)
>  |      >>> s.add(a < 10)
>  |      >>> s.assertions()
>  |      [a > 0, a < 10]
> ```
>
> [source: z3 docs]

**Example:**

```py
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
x = Int('x')
b = Array('I', IntSort(), IntSort())

s = Solver()

s.add(a >= 0)
s.add(x == 0)
s.add(Select(b, 0) == 10)
s.add(Select(b, x) >= a)

opt = Optimize()

opt.add(s.assertions())

obj1 = opt.maximize(a)
obj2 = opt.minimize(a)

opt.set('priority', 'box')

is_sat = opt.check()
assert is_sat

print("Max(a): " + str(obj1.value()))
print("Min(a): " + str(obj2.value()))
```

Output:

```sh
~$ python test.py 
Max(a): 10
Min(a): 0
```